# How to disable package integrity checking via NuGet.exe?

Tags: .net, .net-core, nuget, nuget-package-restore, powershell-core

Since v 4.6 default NuGet client (NuGet.exe) checks package integrity on restore, if applicable.

I've faced with this [issue](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/7674) when restoring [`System.Management.Automation`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Management.Automation/6.0.4) for .NET Core projects. It looks like package authors fail, but it stops development process.

How to temporary disable package integrity checking to allow to install this package?

All I found is [this](https://blog.nuget.org/20170914/NuGet-Package-Signing.html) blog post, which describes security policies, but it doesn't guide how to apply them using NuGet.exe.config or command line switch.

Comment: Roll back your NuGet client to an earlier version?

Comment: @LexLi: I've found another workaround - `dotnet restore` before calling NuGet.exe. It looks like first one ignores integrity checks.

Comment: That's equivalent of "roll back your NuGet client", as `dotnet` command ships usually an older build of NuGet client.